# Can I apply jcrop on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I am new to jcrop. Sorry if this question is trivial.

**Scenario:**
I am trying to build a image crop application. Below is my html markup.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="holder">
        <img>
    </div>
</div>

<style>#container {overflow: hidden;}</style>
```

Here "container" div acts as a viewport. And img element is added using jquery when the user drags and drops the image. Holder div is draggable and the image can be rotated, flipped or moved from its original position. So only a part of the image is visible in the viewport.

**Question:**
Can I apply jcrop on "container" div(viewport) to crop the image?

Answer (score 0):

You know the coordinate of div `container`, so you can do this

```
    $('img').Jcrop({
        setSelect:   [ 100, 100, 50, 50 ]
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Can you explain it little more? I should be able to crop the visible part of the image accurately.

Comment: You should crop the image on server side. So when you have the image and the coordinate, you can do that on server side.